# how to know is application pool memory enough?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate, web-applications, hosting, pool

I'm thinkin to use shared hosting which have application pool of 200MB. Before I buy this service I need to know how much memory my app actually consuming.

And what happens when that application pool size iz reached. With having nhibernate mvc3 applications in mind when sessionFactory is build it should stay in application pool memory and after pool is reached this session factory should be created again. Correct me if wrong.

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very difficult to say whether 200 MB is enough or not, because it depends on how much data your application keeps in memory.

There are various settings in IIS ... For example,

1) If POOL size limit is reached, you can shutdown the application ...
2) If Pool size limit is reached, you can recycle your application pool ...
3) You can reset your application with the new worker processes ...
4) CPU limit settings ... and so on ...

So, it all depends on settings of your application pool by your hosting provider ...

To avoid all these, what you can do is, 1) Ask your hosting provider to give you remote accesss to manage IIS properties of your websites ...  If you have remote access, you can adjust various settings based on your needs ... 2) If you have a budget of roughly $20 a month, Go for a virtual private server hosting ... where you have full liberty to set everything for your IIS.

Comment: I do have remote access, and definit. will move to vps, but I'm still rookie in that field, so shared hosting with managed server are good for now. Any thoughts when having remote access what to look to set proper values (best practices )having application pool in mind. Thanks

Comment: Go to the last settings in your IIS Application pool attributes ... It says about recycling your application pool ... There is an option called "Virtual Memory Limit" and it give you option about what to do if you reach "virtual memory limit". You can set this attribute to have ==> "sessionFactory is build it should stay in application pool memory and after pool is reached this session factory should be created again."

Answer (score 0):

Use a load testing tool like [apache bench](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/programs/ab.html) and monitor your memory usage.

Comment: Looks like that tool doesn't cover IIS, so if host is using IIS this won't work correct?

Comment: actually, my host is using IIS :)